# ¿Cómo puedo implementar un EventHandler<ActionEvent>?

Tags: java, javafx

Deseo implementar eventos en los botones de mi calculadora la cual desarrollé con JavaFX, pero deseo darle los eventos utilizando `EventHandler<ActionEvent>`, pero hasta ahora no he logrado encontrar la forma de poder implementarlo, me podrían dar alguna sugerencia de cómo podría implementar esos eventos.

Aquí les escribo parte del código de mi calculadora:

Aquí es donde declaro los botones:

```
    AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
    TextField tf_Pantalla = new TextField("");   
    TextField tf_SubPantalla = new TextField("");  

    Button btn_Clean = new Button("C");
    Button btn_Delete = new Button("DEL");

    Button btn_0 = new Button("0");
    Button btn_1 = new Button("1");
    Button btn_2 = new Button("2");
    Button btn_3 = new Button("3");
    Button btn_4 = new Button("4");
    Button btn_5 = new Button("5");
    Button btn_6 = new Button("6");
    Button btn_7 = new Button("7");
    Button btn_8 = new Button("8");
    Button btn_9 = new Button("9");

    Button btn_Punto = new Button(".");
    Button btn_Suma = new Button("+");
    Button btn_Resta = new Button("-");
    Button btn_Multiplicacion = new Button("x");
    Button btn_Division = new Button("/");
    Button btn_Igual = new Button("=");
```

Aquí es donde creé mis métodos separados por tipo de botón:

```
private void num1 (){}

private void num2 (){}

private void num3 (){}
```

Comment: Elimina la imagen con él código, y edita la pregunta, pegando el mismo en texto. Revisa el enlace sobre [ask]. También puede serte de interés el [tour].

Comment: muchas gracias por el dato, ahorita lo hago

Answer (score 1):

Muy frecuentemente se usa una expresión de clase anónima ([*anonymous class*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)) para poder definir la acción del botón directamente donde se define el botón:

```java
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
});
```

Este trozo de código proviene del [ejemplo *Hello World* de la documentación de JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm).

---

En Java 8 se introdujeron las [interfaces funcionales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8), que son cualquier interfaz que tenga un único método abstracto (sin valor predeterminado). Para cualquier interfaz funcional, se puede usar una [expresión lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27) (una expresión que define una función anónima) para crear un objeto que [sea de una clase anónima implícita que] implemente la interfaz. En este caso, la definición del método abstracto de la interfaz quedará definido por la expresión lambda que se haya usado. Ejemplo:

```java
interface Duck {
    public void quack();
}
```

```
// ----------- en main(), u otro método, o jshell -------------

// La expresión () -> { ... } siguiente es una expresión lambda:
Duck d = () -> { System.out.prinln("quack! quack!"); };

// Ahora d es un objecto de una clase anónima que implementa Duck, cuya
// implementacion de Duck::quack es { System.out.prinln("quack! quack!"); }
System.out.println(d.getClass().getSimpleName());
d.quack();
```

```
Main$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800ba0840
quack! quack!
```

Si la interfaz que se quiere implementar con la expresión lambda no se indica explícitamente (al contrario de, por ejemplo, `new Duck(() -> { ... })` o `Duck d = () -> { ... }`), Java la inferirá mediante el contexto, típicamente siendo éste el tipo del parámetro de un método al cual se pasa el lambda como argumento (por ejemplo, suponiendo que `a.foo()` está declarado como `A::foo(Duck d);`, entonces la expresión lambda en `a.foo(() -> { ... });` implementará `Duck`).

Por lo tanto, el ejemplo anterior de JavaFX se puede simplificar a lo siguiente:

```java
Button btn = new Button();
btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction(() -> { System.out.println("Hello World!"); });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por esa información, ya logre poner los eventos , muchas gracias.

Comment: Esta respuesta es correcta, pero sería todavía mejor si incluyera cómo hacer el setOnAction con lambdas en vez de clases anónimas: btn.setOnAction(()->System.out.println("Hello World"));